# can I add content by search web part to my SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have a SharePoint hosted app with many pages and workflow. Can I add content by search web part to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in short is yes. At last I could add content by search web part to the app. Thanks to CHRIS O'BRIEN for his article

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/08/working-with-web-parts-within.html